# What type of token is the authentication token provided in the web federation playground when you sign in as a web identity?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm sorry for what appears to be somewhat of a dumb question, but I'm playing around in [AWS' Web Identity Federation playground](https://web-identity-federation-playground.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) and am not clear what type of access (authorization) token I am receiving when I first log in and the provider redirects to the callback URL. I first log in with my Amazon.com account, and Amazon supplies me with an access token. I understand that I will trade this in for an STS token so I can assume a specific role defined for me, but I wanted to inspect the token using the [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) site:
[image]
This all makes sense to me, but when I paste it into the **jwt.io** form to see its plaintext contents, I get an `Invalid Signature` error. If this is not a JWT, where is the information for access scopes (like `profile` and expiration windows (like `3600`) stored then?

I'm guessing this means that the access token is not a JWT token, but rather only a simple string combination that has no real-world meaning and 
basically says "*Check this token is valid and then grant whoever gave you this token the permissions associated with it*"? Is this always true for every web identity provider (Amazon, Google, Facebook, etc.)? Does the fact that `token_type=bearer` in the query string of the redirect URL mean that it cannot be a JWT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If jwt.io says `Invalid Signature`, it’s not necessarily because the token is not valid, it is probably because **you have not provided jwt.io with a valid signing key**. In the signature box on the right, paste the signing key.

Comment: Where I would I be able to find the signing key from the authorization/access token provided back from Amazon?

Comment: You don’t need to verify the signature to read the token. This is a mechanism that a server uses to make sure that the token was issued by the person it claims to be issued by. If you need to see the info inside the token, jwt.io will display this, and it doesn’t need to verify. The `Invalid Signature` is just letting you know that jwt.io didn’t validate it.